# How to reflexively use the verb вынимать?

Tags: глаголы

I found this definition located on [AbbyyLingvo](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/en/Translate/ru-en/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), and was curious to how to use it in a reflexive manner. For example, if I wanted to say, "I am withdrawing myself from the situation" would I simple say, using вынимать, "Я вынимаю себя из ситуации?" Or could I use a 'ся' ending, "Я вынимаюсь из ситуации?" Or how could you say, "The government is 'withdrawing/pulling out' of the war?

Sometimes I am confused as to when I can use a a reflexive verb or 'себя.' I wanted to say, "I cannot express myself correctly in Russian," and a native speaker said I could say, "Я не могу выражать себя правильно на русском" or "Я не могу выражаться правильно на русском," both of which carry the same meaning. Which one is correct?

> вынимать
>
> (что-л.) несовер. - вынимать; совер. - вынуть take out, pull out;
>   extract (извлекать); draw out (деньги из банка и т. п. || money from
>   bank, etc.)
>
> (ленту) unload, (напр., разъём из гнезда) unplug
>
> withdraw
>
> take out

Comment: The word also has a sexual overtone, similar to English word "withdraw".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I am withdrawing myself from the situation" - вынимать is not the best word here. Вытаскивать is better in this particular example. Also, neither has have a reflexive form (well, you can make it, but it would sound weird or/and funny 8) ). "Я вытаскиваю себя из этой ситуации" sounds more Russian. We are kinda dragging or pulling ourselves from tricky situations.

[Вытаскивать](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%F2%E0%F1%EA%E8%E2%E0%F2%FC)

"Я [вытягиваю](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%F2%FF%E3%E8%E2%E0%F2%FC) себя из этой ситуации" - also possible, more slang.

"Я [выбираюсь](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%E1%E8%F0%E0%F2%FC%F1%FF) из этой ситуации" - an example with reflexive verb.

"Я [выхожу](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%F5%EE%E4%E8%F2%FC) из этой ситуации" - an example without reflexive words or endings

"Я [вылезаю](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E2%FB%EB%E5%E7%E0%F2%FC) из этой ситуации" - more colloquial/slang

"The government is 'withdrawing/pulling out' of the war" - in this example, "выйти из войны"  could work, especially if you mean a country. http://wordweb.ru/history_ww2/50_02.htm the title of this article is "An attempt for Finland to pull out of the war". Your example would be something like: "Правительство вышло из войны". Though, it sounds a bit strange to me, because we usually mean the country pulling out of the war, not specifically it's government. So, with a loose translation, I would say "Страна вышла из войны".

"I cannot express myself correctly in Russian" - both are possible, though it is better to use a reflexive verb here, "выражать себя" - is a bit lyrical. "Я не могу правильно выражаться по-русски/на русском".

A little remark on "can" here. You may say "Я не умею правильно выражаться по-русски/на русском" and it would mean that you cannot express yourself correctly **because you haven't learned how to do that yet**. This would sound a bit better because that way you suggest that you are learning Russian and trying to express yourself correctly, and that gives you more respect. You can add "ещё/пока ещё" (still/for now) to make it even more naturally sounding. "Я пока ещё не умею правильно выражаться по-русски" - sounds pretty natural.

Answer (score 1):

`Вынимать` 'to take out' is used for taking out a material object from a material container, no way using it while talking about situations, wars, governments, banks, or anything that abstract. The same goes about its reflexive counterpart, `выниматься` 'to be [able to be] taken out'. You can use this verb to talk about taking a handkerchief out of the pocket, fingers out of one's mouth, a plug from a socket, a memory card from a card-reader, a photo from your album, a $100 bill out of your wallet, etc.